# Does order of the Columns matter while performing Z ORDERING on delta table?

Tags: pyspark, databricks, delta-lake

I have a huge (batch data) delta table and would like perform Z ORDERING on 2 columns.

1. TRASACTION_ID - high cardinality
2. PRODUCT_ID - Relatively less cardinality
   While Z ORDERING which column should come first in the above case? Or Does it matter at all?

Follow up question: I know that Z ORDERING is helpful while performing filter or where. What if my queries only have joins and groupBy-aggregations, is it useful to use Z ORDERING in these cases??

Tried searching blogs but could not find anything. Since I have huge table, moreover Optimize is expensive command did not get chance to run experimentation.

Comment: what are the join conditions?